# How to fix "[WinError 10013] An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions')"?

Tags: python, windows, pip, python-docx

I need to read and get the style (strong in this case) of a paragraph in a .docx so I tried to install the `python-docx` package (in anaconda pv3.9 and pv2.7) using

```
pip install python-docx
```

But I get the error below:

```
(python27) C:\Users\Alberto\.anaconda>pip install python-docx
DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 will reach the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 won't be maintained after that date. A future version of pip will drop support for Python 2.7. More details about Python 2 support in pip, can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x000000000476D148>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 10013] An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions',)': /simple/python-docx/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x000000000476D6C8>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 10013] An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions',)': /simple/python-docx/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x000000000476DAC8>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 10013] An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions',)': /simple/python-docx/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x000000000476DEC8>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 10013] An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions',)': /simple/python-docx/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x000000000479D308>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 10013] An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions',)': /simple/python-docx/
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement python-docx (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for python-docx
```

In python3.9:

```
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x000002BEA5A7CBE0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10013] An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions')': /simple/python-docx/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x000002BEA219DB80>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10013] An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions')': /simple/python-docx/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x000002BEA5A78F70>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10013] An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions')': /simple/python-docx/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x000002BEA5A78D60>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10013] An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions')': /simple/python-docx/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x000002BEA59DC250>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10013] An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions')': /simple/python-docx/
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement python-docx (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for python-docx
```

Comment: Do you get the same error when installing any other Python package? If so, then it's not specific to python-docx.

Answer (score -1):

could you please try this version and update if it is working for you?

```
pip install python-docx=0.8.11
```

I tried installing on python 3.9, this version worked for me.

Cheers..

Comment: same error for me :(